# JS/HTML5 - Redraw canvas with image data from an array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement an undo-function for a canvas. Basically people can draw on a canvas, and then restore it to the state it was before. That's the theory.
I save the current imageData every time I call a function draw. It's saved in an array eD(namespace).history. Drawing works fine, even if I manipulate the imageData. Here's my draw-function (cD is a namespace aswell):

```
editorClass.prototype.draw = function(){
    eD.history.push(cD.imageData);
    cD.context.putImageData(cD.imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Now if I try to undo my changes I've made in between, I use a function called undo, which looks like that:

```
editorClass.prototype.undo = function(){
    var temp = eD.history.pop();
    cD.context.createImageData(cD.width,cD.height); //Can leave this out, nothing changes
    cD.context.putImageData(temp, 0, 0);
}
```

As mentioned above, that won't work. The canvas I work with is created once the user loads the site. cD.imageData originates from this function:

```
editorClass.prototype.getPixels = function(){
    cD.imageData = cD.context.getImageData(0, 0, cD.width, cD.height);
    // get the image data of the context and save them into namespace
    cD.pixels = cD.imageData.data;
    // get the pixels

    cD.pixelsLength = cD.width * cD.height * 4;
    // precompute the length of the pixel array
}
```

Both namespaces are visible, if needed. Since I'm pretty new to canvas, it might be a simple question - so if you have improvements: I'm an empty bucked, fill me in ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing all the code I'm not sure exactly why yours isn't working but I suspect its due to only trying to do a `putImageData` with the pixel array and not the image data object.

Heres a demo I wrote that works

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/JMKzJ/)**

And here is the relevant Code

```
var savedData = [];   

undoButt.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // as long as there is data put it onto the canvas.
    if (savedData.length > 0) {
        var imgData = savedData.pop();
        drawCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    }
});

drawCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    // push the current state
    var imgData = drawCtx.getImageData(0, 0, drawCanvas.width, drawCanvas.height);
    savedData.push(imgData);

});
```

Its the same concept you used, it seems to work alright.

Comment: Hi,thanks you've helped me more than you might think. It's actually working now. When I refactored my code yesterday I thought that I'm doing something wrong regarding the canvas handling. Seeing you're code I realized, that mine was alright. It was rather a mistake in the logic. I was saving the imageData when I drew the canvas, so after the imageData already was manipulated. All I had to do is to save the imageData not after but before it was manipulated - It was pretty late yesterday ;) Anyway, thanks that's it!